# What is more efficient, loading all javascript at once or loading it as required per-page?

Tags: javascript

I always read about having to concatenate and minify your javscript to decrease load times, but I'm not sure about what to do in case of a multi-page application. Is it better to concatenate and minify ALL javascript for the entire site, include the same file in every page and rely on caching or is it better to only group the specific JS needed for each page separately?

Comment: if the file (after minification & gzip) is small, then load it with the page. This really depends how to structure your code. I have components, and also page controllers, which use different components, so obviously page controllers are unique per-page, but they aren't so big. components could be re-used anywhere, so I prefer them to always be in the code. (for 0-time initialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It varies.

In my case, I have an online game. There is a core JS file that all pages use (some people would use jQuery, but I have a custom toolbox - it's effectively the same thing). Then there are individual JS files for each page, such as `party.js`, `summary.js`, `forum.js` and so on. So each page of the site loads two JS files in total.

Now, I *could* simply compile all of those individual JS files into one big one. But if I have just the tiniest edit in one of the most obscure pages of the site? Suddenly everyone has to re-download the entire massive file.

With my system, they would only have to download the individual file that changed. Since the game is in ongoing development, this is probably for the best.

**However,** if you have a site that's basically done, and will only be getting minor patches or infrequent updates, then compiling everything into one file will be better overall, because visitors will download it once and then not have to worry about it.

So, basically, it varies.

Comment: Agreed. caching one file is more important than anything. HTTP requests are "expensive".

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating multi-page applications, you should try to separate it out into different bundles.

It's all about "time to glass". If you include stuff that you don't need on the page, then it will load slower, which users never want.

I would suggest setting up a base bundle that is used between pages and is needed for everything, cache the hell out of it, and then set up page specific bundles.

Comment: why would it load slower? 1. it will be cached so only the very first time it **might** be slower 2. you won't feel it slow because the js file won't probably exceed 200k max, which is meaningless. probably in his case it's more like 50kb (gziped) because only HUGE websites get a bloated JS file above 200kb (which is a rare case)

Comment: Bundling everything because it's a bigger file. I have worked at places that had bloated js above 200kb. You're right, once it's cached and gzipped it wouldn't be a problem. But as always, the less in a file, the faster the download (even if it is ms)

Comment: Facebook is a good example for this, they load each isolated component serially and each component has an "importance" number, so of course the outline of the website is the most important, then Feed, then Chat and so on. If all the code was in one huge file, it wouldn't load as fast because Facebook is a monster website. but, this isn't the case for "normal" websites, which are 99% fine with one file. (i build mine automatically using GULP from many separate files)